# Gradual color for points in matlab 3d scatter according to number in the list

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, 3d, scatter

I have data that includes coordinates x,y,z. I made a 3d scatter plot. However, it's essential for me to see the sequence of these points according to the index number by filling the points with gradual color. 
My current code is

```
data = importdata('12.txt');
x = data (:,1);
y = data (:,2);
z = data (:,3);
scatter3 (x,y,z);
xlabel ('S1');
ylabel ('S2');
zlabel ('S3');
title ('3d scatter plot for 2nd specimen');
scatter3(x,y,z,'filled')
view(-30,10)
```

P.S. Matlab is new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you an example:

```
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
z = 1:10;

MarkerSize = 5;
SizeVector = repmat(MarkerSize ,length(x),1);

ColorVector = summer(length(x));

h = scatter3(x,y,z,SizeVector,ColorVector,'filled');

view(-30,10)
```

Matlab can generate color vectors (RGB) for different colormap.

In this case I choose the summer's colormap, but if you check the doc there is a lot of different options.

**Result:**

[image]